# git from bash script on Windows using MinGW is not configured

Tags: windows, bash, git, mingw

I am writing a bash script that needs to perform some git actions. I'm working on windows using MinGW.

running `bash test.sh`

with `test.sh` having the content:

```
echo "git config --global user.name -> $(git config --global user.name)"
```

This prints:

`git config --global user.name ->`

Whereas going on powershell and typing `git config --global user.name` prints `my_actual_user_name`.

I'd like in this case to user my user settings on git, which would include having access to my ssh keys, which it is not doing. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use, both in your script and PowerShell:

```
git config --show-scope --show-origin user.name
```

You will see exactly which file is used to query that setting.
If they differ, that would explain your difference in output.

---

The [OP Mefitico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3007075/mefitico) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73613600/git-from-bash-script-on-windows-using-mingw-is-not-configured/73617824#comment130020189_73617824) `HOME` was not set.

Setting a user environment variable `HOME` to `%USERPROFILE%` is enough for a git bash session to access the same global `.gitconfig` setting file as a Git PowerShell session.